# WooCommerce: Date as attribute term

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I'm relatively new to using WooCommerce so all advice would be great.
I've got a number of inclass training course products I'm trying to sell. Each have multiple date offerings.

Is there a way I can set the attribute term to a date value or do I have to manually add every possible date?

Is there another way to solve this problem, I am just ignorant off?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

When you add the products and while entering the product data in general tab you will see two fields REGULAR PRICE & SALE PRICE beside the SALE PRICE text box you will see the schedule click on it you will find the DATE fields from Date to Date variations in price you can set it from there. Here I set an Image

[image]
 Here you will Find the date fields to set

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Easy to understand...Thanks @Dharit Soni